# Need help reading rows From CSV in Java

Tags: java, csv

I want to write a code that when a button is clicked (The GUI is functional) it will display all the requested data from the person that is logged in. There will be a CSV File with different levels of access. They will contain the log in info and what status they are. Also There will be another CSV File that will house personal data (Fictional) Such as Name, Short Bio, Job responsibilities etc.

From my understanding CSV Files will only allow you to print out the entire file or you have to hardcode which line to use. so My question is this. Is there a way to code in Java to look for a similar ID number to the logged in user to display their info?

Like if user Rad52 logged in the code would parse over the other rows and find user id Rad52 and display only that information?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Use `if` to test if a condition is true or false (like "the current row's first cell is equal to "Rad52"), and act accordingly. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to read a CSV file post which you may use if conditions to get the data you need. Here's a link to get you started with the CSV file:

http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/05/27/parse-csv-files-in-java/

Comment: Thanks I also found another site http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/ That explained it in the simplest details.

Also I found out how to set the currently logged in user. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/ to help you parse csv files